# Inequality and Growth: the Role of Democracy

Tags: development-economics

In the [Alesina and Rodrik (1994)](https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/4551798/alesina_distributive.pdf?sequence=2) study on the impact of inequality on growth, why did they include a dummy for democracies in their empirical estimation? In other words, why did they want to study whether the impact would be different for democracies vis-a-vis non-democracies?

Comment: Welcome, I changed the title and added a ungated version of the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Alesina and Rodrik (1994) wanted to study **whether the impact would be different for democracies vis-a-vis non-democracies** because they show that

> in a democracy (where the ``median voter theorem'' applies) the rate
>   of taxation is higher and the rate of growth lower, the more unequal
>   is the distribution of wealth.

Their model implies that democracies with a more unequal distribution of capital ownership grow less rapidly than more egalitarian democracies. They argue this is because 
the median voter has a relatively small endowment of capital when wealth is unequally distributed, and thus favors high taxes on capital which keep growth low.

They wanted to estimate this prediction by adding a dummy variable for democracies vis-a-vis non-democracies